# PHP if url extension action=discussion condition use

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I want use some style only for url extension /?action=discussion 
How can I use it by PHP condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP get method to process these variables.

```
<?php if( $_GET['action'] == 'discussion' ) { ?>
    It's True.
<?php } else { ?>
    It's False.
<?php { ?>
```

Comment: Is it working only when url extension is  /?action=discussion ?

Comment: Yes because we are only checking for if `action=discussion` in my code. We can change it to use many other conditions too.

Comment: The custom style only working for http://interactionlibrary.jacklynn.com/wiki/frequency/?action=discussion this page? Please confirm once.. and thanks

Comment: No, it will work for which ever page have "?action=discussion" in URL. If you or someone add `?action=discussion` in your homepage then it will work there too. Isn't that what you asked?

Comment: http://interactionlibrary.jacklynn.com/wiki/frequency/?action=discussion I want to use some style for this url... means /?action=discussion the extension

Comment: Yes, it will work for this extension only. Please try it.

Comment: Then please select this question as answered. :) Thanks